# Trouble with slow/intermittently failing web access on a Linux desktop and multiple Android devices except when using a VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

All our devices are having trouble accessing the Internet today. Some web pages load within the expected time, though I believe on the slow end. Others just fail to load.

However, when I connect through VPN with each device the issue goes away.

All connections go through an ancient Linksys WRT54G—stock firmware, it’s version 6, so no resources to run anything else—which is connected in turn to a Comcast Wi-Fi router/modem that is in bridge mode. Everything set to DHCP.

`ifconfig` ***with*** VPN:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:50:99:4a:82:e3  
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d250:99ff:fe4a:82e3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:153883 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:125377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:172285690 (172.2 MB)  TX bytes:39495543 (39.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6724 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6724 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1462651 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:1462651 (1.4 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.196.1.6  P-t-P:10.196.1.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8051 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:7218519 (7.2 MB)  TX bytes:791798 (791.7 KB)
```

`ifconfig` ***without*** VPN:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:50:99:4a:82:e3  
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d250:99ff:fe4a:82e3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:154232 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:125803 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:172349264 (172.3 MB)  TX bytes:39585824 (39.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6807 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6807 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1474631 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:1474631 (1.4 MB)
```

`resolv.conf` ***with*** VPN:

```
nameserver 209.222.18.222
nameserver 209.222.18.218
nameserver 75.75.75.75
search hsd1.ca.comcast.net
```

`resolv.conf` ***without*** VPN:

```
nameserver 75.75.75.75
nameserver 75.75.76.76
nameserver 208.67.222.222
search hsd1.ca.comcast.net
```

Wow, pages I clicked a few minutes ago JUST loaded as I type this.

Without VPN I am unable to ping those `75.75.75.7*` nameservers. 
I *am* able to ping them when connected to VPN. Manually setting DNS—and reconnecting—in network-manager or editing `resolv.conf` as a test doesn’t seem to help.

It doesn’t matter if I connect via ethernet or Wi-Fi with the Linux desktop. My Samsung tablet fails to get an IP address even though signal is strong. Android phone connects to Wi-Fi but is painfully slow on most pages.

I have power cycled the Linksys router and computer, tried manually setting DNS, starting chrome with `--no-proxy-server` and disabling proxies in firefox preferences (have not set any but just in case).

I’ve seen Firefox take only a few moments saying “looking up [website]” before getting stuck at the next stage (connecting to? I think) but now it gets stuck at “looking up…”

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

I wish I could state what was wrong clearly in case it could help someone else but it was never clear to myself or the techs, though the network is back up now. That said, here's my best guess, hope it helps someone, specifically because things were made more difficult since the symptoms actually changed over time.

I think the comcast modem may have kept dropping out of bridge mode so that I kept ending up with two routers chained together instead of a router and a modem in bridge mode.

It is now back out of bridge mode and my router is removed from the setup. Everything is working within expectations (comcast router's wifi has horrible signal strength).

Comcast was never able to fix it so I could return to using my router, in fact it got worse and ended with my router no longer obtaining anything via dhcp. Earlier during the problem it did populate, just would work very slowly or not at all depending on the site, and before yesterday it worked fine. My computer had no problem obtaining IP and dns when connected to modem in bridge mode.

They had to reset the modem over and over and over, probably 10 times before it worked. Turns out they can send a "go in to bridge mode" or "leave bridge mode" signal, but can't tell at all which mode it is in. Before this started the wifi light was a good telltail: if on, then not bridge mode. That light no longer works at all after some initial flickers during startup. That led to complications since I was relying on that to indicated mode.

This may be one of those ugly situations where there are multiple problems making it hard to fix. There was definitely an issue with the modem. Now there seems to possibly be one with my router.

I didn't know about mtr, thank you - will install it momentarily for next time.